# Discord.py: How do I use @commands.check on an on_message event

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to get the bot to send an emoji when someone else sends one. I have managed to get this to work, but when I use @commands.check to make sure the bot is not responding to itself, it responds anyway and the bot gets stuck in a loop of replying to itself.

```
def is_it_me_event(message):
    if message.author.id == 1234567890:
        return False

@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
@commands.check(is_it_me_event)
async def on_message(self, message):
    if str(message.content) == ":smile:":
        await message.channel.send(":smile:")
```

I know I can do this with an if statement inside the function itself, but is there a way of doing this with the commands.check decorator or is this not compatible with functions that aren't commands?

Comment: "*I know I can do this with an if statement inside the function itself*" - Then why don't you do it? This way you make it unnecessarily difficult for yourself

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this so if I need to, I can use multiple decorators on a function to set up a bunch of conditions before the function gets called. Rather than having a bunch of reused nested if statements actually inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work:

```
def check_author_isnt_self(func):

    async def decorator(ctx, *args, **kwargs):
        message = args[0]
        if message.author.id != 1234567890:
            await func(ctx, message)

    decorator.__name__ = func.__name__
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    decorator.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters=tuple(sig.parameters.values())[1:])
    return decorator

@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
@check_author_isnt_self
async def on_message(self, message):
    if str(message.content) == ":smile:":
        await message.channel.send(":smile:")
```

This article explains how this works: https://scribe.rip/@cantsayihave/decorators-in-discord-py-e44ce3a1aae5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, you can't decorate your `on_message` function with a `@commands.check(...)` because it isn't a command. However, you can set up a predicate for these events:

```py
def check_author_isnt_self():
    def decorator(func):
        async def wrapper(message):
            return message.author.id != 1234567890:
            # or `return message.author.id != self.bot.id` as better practice
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
@check_author_isnt_self()
async def smile_back(self, message):
    if str(message.content) == ":smile:":
        await message.channel.send(":smile:")
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that @commands.check() doesn't work here. I couldn't get this code to work but I've found a solution anyway